# Trying to send email with Django send_mail and SendGrid

Tags: django, sendgrid

I'm trying to send mail with SendGrid, but whenever I send an HTML formatted email, it shows the HTML tags in the email rather than formatting the HTML as desired. Here's what I'm trying to send:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
  <p>Hi!<br>
     How are you?<br>
  </p>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's my code:

```
 def send(self, group=None):
        current_site = Site.objects.get_current()
        domain = unicode(current_site.domain)
        ctx = {
            "group": group,
            "signup_code": self,
            "domain": domain,
        }
        msg = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
        subject = render_to_string("signup_codes/invite_user_subject.txt", ctx)
        msg['subject'] = render_to_string("signup_codes/invite_user_subject.txt", ctx)
        message = render_to_string("signup_codes/invite_user.txt", ctx)
        text = "Hi!\nHow are you?\n"
        part1 = MIMEText(text, 'plain')
        part2 = MIMEText(message,'html')
        msg.attach(part1)
        msg.attach(part2)
        send_mail(subject, message, settings.DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL, [self.email])
        self.sent = datetime.datetime.now()
        self.save()
```

Note: `invite_user.txt` contains the html above.

Any insight into why it's not recognizing that this is HTML and formatting it accordingly? Am I missing something?

Comment: You never send this `msg` you've created. You just send_mail 2 strings. Look into django html email and just use their mail types.

Comment: Ok thanks -- it's still not formatting it though -- any idea why? It just displays it as text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default the Django mailer sends only the text part of an email.  You need to either set it to html (which is bad practice) or use the EmailMultiAlternatives class.  So, I think this is what you're looking for really:

```
from django.core.mail import EmailMultiAlternatives

def send(self, group=None):
  current_site = Site.objects.get_current()
  domain = unicode(current_site.domain)
  ctx = {
      "group": group,
      "signup_code": self,
      "domain": domain,
  }

  subject = render_to_string("signup_codes/invite_user_subject.txt", ctx)
  text_content = "Hi!\nHow are you?\n"
  html_content = render_to_string("signup_codes/invite_user.txt", ctx)

  msg = EmailMultiAlternatives(subject, text_content, settings.DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL, [self.email])
  msg.attach_alternative(html_content, "text/html")

  msg.send()
```

---

Also, there's an official SendGrid python package which you might want to consider as an alternative to using the built in Django functions.  Check it out here:

> https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-python/